# Regular expression captures unwanted string

Tags: regex

I have created the following expression: (.NET regex engine)

```
((-|\+)?\w+(\^\.?\d+)?)

hello , hello^.555,hello^111, -hello,+hello, hello+, hello^.25, hello^-1212121
```

It works well except that :

- it captures the term 'hello+' but without the '+' : this group should not be captured at all
- the last term 'hello^-1212121' as 2 groups 'hello' and '-1212121' both should be ignored

The strings to capture are as follows :

- word can have a + or a - before it
- or word can have a ^ that  is followed by a positive number (not necessarily an integer)
- words are separated by commas and any number of white spaces (both not part of the capture)

A few examples of valid strings to capture :

- hello^2
- hello^.2
- +hello
- -hello
- hello

**EDIT**

I have found the following expression which effectively captures all these terms, it's not really optimized but it just works :

```
([a-zA-Z]+(?= ?,))|((-|\+)[a-zA-Z]+(?=,))|([a-zA-Z]+\^\.?\d+)
```

Comment: So should `hello` match?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot about it, I've just updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there are some issues to tackle here:

```
((-|+)?\w+(\^.?\d+)?)
    ^        ^
```

The `+` and `.` should be escaped like this:

```
((-|\+)?\w+(\^\.?\d+)?)
```

Now, you'll also get `-1212121` there. If your string `hello` is always letters, then you would change `\w` to `[a-zA-Z]`:

```
((-|\+)?[a-zA-Z]+(\^\.?\d+)?)
```

`\w` includes letters, numbers and underscore. So, you might want to restrict it down a bit to only letters.

And finally, to take into consideration of the completely not capturing groups, you'll have to use lookarounds. I don't know of anyway otherwise to get to the delimiters without hindering the matches:

```
(?<=^|,)\s*((-|\+)?[a-zA-Z]+(\^\.?\d+)?)\s*(?=,|$)
```

EDIT: If it cannot be something like `-hello^2`, and if another valid string is `hello^9.8`, then this one will fit better:

```
(?<=^|,)\s*((?:-|\+)?[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\^(?:\d+)?\.?\d+)(?=\s*(?:,|$))
```

And lastly, if capturing the words is sufficient, we can remove the lookarounds:

```
([-+]?[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\^(?:\d+)?\.?\d+)
```

Comment: Fixed, copy/paste broke the expression. Great but it still captures 'hello+' but without the '+' and the last 'hello', both should be ignored. Do you think these cases can be solved only with Regex or would it require extra code ?

Comment: @Aybe Okay, thank you :) I had missed the part about the completely not matching, so I've added one last regex.

Comment: Great it's almost perfect, still captures white space around if there's any. Thank you.

Comment: Forget about my previous comment, i'll just do an extra regex to remove spaces, thank you !!!

Comment: @Aybe you can remove the white spaces after the matches by changing `\s*(?=,|$)` to `\s*(?=\s*(?:,|$))`, but the ones at the back would be difficult since lookbehinds don't usually accept unfixed number of characters ^^;

Comment: Yes, well not sure it is my editor (RegexBuddy) or something else but that changes nothing. That'll do fine anyway, thank you !

Comment: @Aybe If you can extract captured groups, you might simply make some groups non-capturing groups, then you extract all the captured groups. See an [example](http://www.regex101.com/r/wV5vS6)

Comment: @Jerry, The only issue with your solution is that it matches: "+hello^.1" which I'm not sure is required.

Comment: @RobRaisch I didn't notice that Aybe updated the question and was not aware about this constraint. If so, then the one [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/vS2tV7) should cover this possibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you first state what it is you are looking to extract.

You also don't indicate which Regular Expression engine you're using, which is important since they vary in their features, but...

Assuming you want to capture only:

- words that have a leading + or -
- words that have a trailing ^ followed by an optional period followed by one or more digits

and that words are sequences of one or more letters

I'd use:

```
([a-zA-Z]+\^\.?\d+|[-+][a-zA-Z]+)
```

which breaks down into:

```
(              # start capture group
    [a-zA-Z]+    # one or more letters - note \w matches numbers and underscores
    \^           # literal
    \.?          # optional period
    \d+          # one or more digits
|              # OR
    [+-]?        # optional plus or minus
    [a-zA-Z]+    # one or more letters or underscores
)              # end of capture group
```

EDIT

To also capture plain words (without leading or trailing chars) you'll need to rearrange the regexp a little. I'd use:

```
([+-][a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\^(?:\.\d+|\d+\.\d+|\d+)|[a-zA-Z]+)
```

which breaks down into:

```
(              # start capture group
    [+-]         # literal plus or minus
    [a-zA-Z]+    # one or more letters - note \w matches numbers and underscores
|              # OR
    [a-zA-Z]+    # one or more letters
    \^           # literal
    (?:          # start of non-capturing group
      \.           # literal period
      \d+          # one or more digits
    |            # OR
      \d+          # one or more digits       
      \.           # literal period
      \d+          # one or more digits
    |            # OR
      \d+          # one or more digits 
    )            # end of non-capturing group
|              # OR
    [a-zA-Z]+    # one or more letters
)              # end of capture group
```

Also note that, per your updated requirements, this regexp captures both true non-negative numbers (i.e. 0, 1, 1.2, 1.23) as well as those lacking a leading digit (i.e. .1, .12)

FURTHER EDIT

This regexp will only match the following patterns delimited by commas:

- word
- word with leading plus or minus
- word with trailing ^ followed by a positive number of the form \d+, \d+.\d+, or .\d+

  ([+-][A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z]+\^(?:.\d+|\d+(?:.\d+)?)|[A-Za-z]+)(?=,|\s|$)

Please note that the useful match will appear in the first capture group, **not** the entire match.

So, in Javascript, you'd:

```
var src="hello ,  hello ,hello,+hello,-hello,hello+,hello-,hello^1,hello^1.0,hello^.1",
    RE=/([+-][A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z]+\^(?:\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|[A-Za-z]+)(?=,|\s|$)/g;

while(RE.test(src)){
    console.log(RegExp.$1)
}
```

which produces:

```
hello
hello
hello
+hello
-hello
hello^1
hello^1.0
hello^.1
```

Comment: Sorry I'll fix that on my question, your regex is doing great except that it doesn't capture the first 'hello', thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah, you didn't indicate that it should capture only words. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed my question.